# Web Scraping no R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Tenho de baixar a tabela desse link: http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp

Estou tentando utilizar o pacote `rvest`, porém, sem sucesso.

```
library('rvest')
url <- 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas- 
referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp'

site <- read_html(url)
info_Ajuste_HTML <- html_nodes(site,'table')

info_Ajuste <- html_text(info_Ajuste_HTML)

lista_tabela <- site 
lista_tabela <- html_nodes(site, xpath = "//td") 
lista_tabela <- html_table(site, fill = TRUE)

dados <- lista_tabela[[1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o seguinte responde à pegunta. O problema é que a extração da tabela não está nada automatizada, precisa de saber quantas colunas a tabela tem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library('rvest')

url <- 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp'

HTML <- read_html(url) 

dados <- HTML %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//table//td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_replace(",", ".") %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame()

str(dados)
#'data.frame':  294 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ V1: num  1 6 7 11 14 21 22 25 32 33 ...
# $ V2: num  4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.84 4.83 ...
# $ V3: num  0 4.66 5 3.8 4.49 4.66 4.77 4.47 4.53 4.59 ...
```

Comment: Poderia dizer onde conseguiu o xpath?

Comment: Foi na documentação do pacote [rvest](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/rvest.html).